# Understanding correlation in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, correlation

When a database has to perform a join to another table, it may broadly choose from one of the three following strategies:

- sequential scan (when we want most of the records)
- bitmap index scan (when we want some of the records)
- index scan (when we want relatively few records, with a correlated index)

The reasoning here is that if most records need to be retained, it is more efficient to completely ignore the index, avoid I/O penalties, and just read the entire table sequentially.  At the other extreme, clearly if we just need to read a few leaf nodes from an index, this would be faster than reading the entire table.

What is *not* clear to me is what role correlation plays here, and how we should be thinking about it.

Focusing on Postgres, the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/view-pg-stats.html) describes correlation here:

> Statistical correlation between physical row ordering and logical ordering of the column values. This ranges from -1 to +1. When the value is near -1 or +1, an index scan on the column will be estimated to be cheaper than when it is near zero, due to reduction of random access to the disk. (This column is null if the column data type does not have a < operator.)

Here is a way by which we can obtain a correlation value for each column in a given table:

```
SELECT attname, correlation
FROM pg_stats
WHERE tablename = 'your_table';
```

From what I understand, using a secondary index *always* requires doing an I/O seek to the clustered index, to find the data.  As far as I can tell, the only thing which would make I/O better or worse would be if the secondary index were very near to the clustered index on disk.  But it is not clear to me how correlation would be significant for determining how costly an I/O seek is, since a seek is always required.

Can someone give an explanation about what correlation physically means here?  Perhaps my confusion is arising from not understanding how a database performs an index scan.

Comment: Are you assuming that ID -> added_on correlation is the same as physical correlation?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question, because I don't understand correlation.  I really turned up nothing online which convinced me of what was really happening.

Comment: Upon my reading of your quoted docs, I assume that ID *MAY* be correlated to physical ordering (although that's not guaranteed).. but when I look at Id -> timestamp correlation, yeah, it exists.. but that's not relevant to the doc you posted.. it's specifically talking about physical -> logical correlation, not logical -> logical correlation. It doesn't sound like it compares the correlation of columns, but the correlation between each index vs what's on the disk.

So added_on and id may correlate well with physical, and each other, but the optimizer probably doesn't consider that.

Comment: Although, you can bet that if you order the column by ID, it may consider the index on ID to help order the data.. but it cannot use the bitmap index.

Comment: I would appreciate an answer to my question if you think you can produce one :-)

Comment: I'll try-- but I also just realize that I misread B-tree as bitmap (oracle brain still working here, so I apologize).. let me formulate the best answer I  can

Comment: Ithink the explanation in the docs is (mostly) wrong. I did a quick check, and  PK's and unique natural keys appear to have a correlation around 0.5. Indexed FKs are around 0.8. Only low-cardinality columns approach 1.0.

Comment: Your question has inspired a [blog post](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/column-correlation-explained/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correlation only makes sense for columns of a data type that has a total ordering, that is, it supports an [*operator family*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-opclass.html) that belongs to the `btree` access method (the `<`, `<=`, `=`, `>=` and `>` operators).

The correlation is positive if bigger values tend to occur near the physical end of the table and small values near the beginning. A value of 1 means that the values are stored in the table in sorted order, -1 means that they are stored in descending order.

An index scan in PostgreSQL works like this:

1. The first matching entry is located in the index.
2. If the [*visibility map*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/storage-vm.html) indicates that the corresponding table block contains only tuples that are visible to everybody *and* we need no column that is not stored in the index, we have a result and continue with step 4 (if the optimizer thinks that this works for most index entries, it will plan an [*index only scan*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html)).
3. The corresponding row is fetched from the table and checked for visibility. If it is visible and satisfies the filter condition, we have found a result.
4. traverse the index in the scan direction to find the next index entry and see if it satisfies the scan condition. If yes, go back to the second step, else we are done.

This causes *random reads* of table blocks, unless they are already in shared buffers.

Now if the correlation is high, two things are more likely to happen:

- The next tuple found in the index scan is in the same table block as the previous tuple. Then it is already in shared buffers and does not cause a read.

  All in all, you'll end up hitting fewer distinct table blocks: the index entries next to each other tend to be close to each other too, often in the same block.
- If the next index entry does not point to the same table block as the previous one, it is likely to point to the next table block. This leads to sequential reads of the table blocks, which on spinning disks is more efficient than random reads.

Let me illustrate that with an example, assuming an index on a perfectly correlated column:

The first index entry found points to table block 42, the second one too, the third to the 30th one point to block 43, the next 20 index entries will point to block 44.

So the index scan will visit 50 tuples, but it will only read 3 blocks from disk, and these it reads in sequential order (first block 42, then block 43, then block 44).

If there were no correlation, the 50 tuples would likely be in different table blocks (assuming the table is large), which would mean 50 random disk reads.

So index scans are cheaper when the correlation is high, and backwards index scans are cheaper if the correlation is low. The optimizer uses the correlation to adjust the estimated costs accordingly.

Comment: I follow the first (of two) bullet points, but I don't understand the adjacent block argument.  In any case, would I be correct in assuming that the shared buffers are the reason why high correlation makes an index scan attractive?  That is to say, without the possibility of shared buffers, an index scan would always tend to generate random I/O?

Comment: I tried to make both bullet points clearer. Yes, without shared buffers (and the file system cache) the first point wouldn't give any benefits.

Comment: Thanks for the insights.  I'll mark this correct in a bit assuming nothing else comes along.  The implementation details you've provided are surprisingly absent from everything I have read on this subject; but they're necessary to understand what is really happening under the hood.  With your explanation, everything makes sense.  Thanks again.

Comment: I have added an example that should make it clearer. I guess that you have to go to the (well documented and open) source for details like that.

Comment: So the correlation only affects the query plan if we want to fetch more than one row? (according to the response, the *next* tuple might be located in the same or adjacent block). So for queries filtering on primary index, high correlation makes no difference?

Comment: @jimis Yes, it makes a difference for index scans that scan many rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real definition could be found by reading the source ;-)

- The statistics collector *probably* uses {ctid,attribvalue} pairs to estimate the physical<-->logical correlation
- The planner *may* use these coefficents to estimate the number of pages to be fetched

As an example, here are the stats for my twitter-sucker-DB, running on a Raspberry Pi:
(currently circa 3.5M rows)

---

```
\connect twitters

SELECT version();
SELECT count(*) from tweets;

\d tweets

SELECT attname, correlation, n_distinct -- , null_frac
FROM pg_stats
WHERE tablename = 'tweets'
AND schemaname = 'public';
```

---

```
You are now connected to database "twitters" as user "postgres".
                                                          version                                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.6.9 on armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, compiled by gcc (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 32-bit
(1 row)

  count  
---------
 3525068
(1 row)

                                      Table "public.tweets"
     Column     |           Type           |                      Modifiers                       
----------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 seq            | bigint                   | not null default nextval('tweets_seq_seq'::regclass)
 id             | bigint                   | not null
 user_id        | bigint                   | not null
 sucker_id      | integer                  | not null default 0
 created_at     | timestamp with time zone | 
 is_dm          | boolean                  | not null default false
 body           | text                     | 
 in_reply_to_id | bigint                   | not null default 0
 parent_seq     | bigint                   | not null default 0
 is_reply_to_me | boolean                  | not null default false
 is_retweet     | boolean                  | not null default false
 did_resolve    | boolean                  | not null default false
 is_stuck       | boolean                  | not null default false
 need_refetch   | boolean                  | not null default false
 is_troll       | boolean                  | not null default false
 fetch_stamp    | timestamp with time zone | not null default now()
Indexes:
    "tweets_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (seq)
    "tweets_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
    "tweets_userid_id" UNIQUE, btree (user_id, id)
    "tweets_created_at_idx" btree (created_at)
    "tweets_du_idx" btree (created_at, user_id)
    "tweets_id_idx" btree (id) WHERE need_refetch = true
    "tweets_in_reply_to_id_created_at_idx" btree (in_reply_to_id, created_at) WHERE is_retweet = false AND did_resolve = false AND in_reply_to_id > 0
    "tweets_in_reply_to_id_fp" btree (in_reply_to_id)
    "tweets_parent_seq_fk" btree (parent_seq)
    "tweets_ud_idx" btree (user_id, created_at)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "tweets_parent_seq_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_seq) REFERENCES tweets(seq)
    "tweets_user_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES tweeps(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "tweets" CONSTRAINT "tweets_parent_seq_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_seq) REFERENCES tweets(seq)

    attname     | correlation | n_distinct 
----------------+-------------+------------
 seq            |   -0.519016 |         -1  #<<-- PK
 id             |   -0.519177 |         -1  #<<-- NaturalKey
 user_id        |  -0.0994714 |       1024  # FK to tweeps, cadinality ~= 5000)
 sucker_id      |    0.846975 |          5  # Low Card
 created_at     |   -0.519177 |  -0.762477  # High Card
 is_dm          |           1 |          1
 body           |   0.0276537 |  -0.859618
 in_reply_to_id |    0.104481 |      25956  # FK to self
 parent_seq     |    0.954938 |       1986  # FK To self
 is_reply_to_me |           1 |          2
 is_retweet     |    0.595322 |          2
 did_resolve    |    0.909326 |          2
 is_stuck       |           1 |          1
 need_refetch   |           1 |          1
 is_troll       |           1 |          1
 fetch_stamp    |   -0.519572 |      95960  # High Card
(16 rows)
```

---

The strange thing here is that the (mostly)ascending columns {seq,id,created_at,fetch_stamp} have negative correlations, the self-reference-FKs {in_reply_to_id,parent_seq} positive ones. My guess is that for `n_distinct = -1` (:=unique) columns, the correlation is not used at all, maybe only the sign.

Answer (score 0):

First, we've got several things at play that are making it difficult to fully explain, but I'll try, and pardon me if some of this is just plain obvious to you already.

So, random IOs are expensive because we're reading random blocks of data all over the disk.
It's much faster to bulk read several blocks in a row (especially on a magnetic drive, non-ssd)

Now one step further, the docs you're quoting are specifically talking about an index scan, which is typically a range, not an exact value.

So when an index is correlated (can be forced by clustering the table by the index in question), and it's looking for a range of values IE  (where Id between 1000000 and 1001000), the locations (block locations) returned by "scanning" the index are going to most likely be in nearly the same location on the disk.

So it can go to index ABC, find the 1000 rows and figure out which blocks it needs to read, and perhaps get them in a very few number of seeks. The 1 (or so) extra seeks to get the index was worth it.

Now, if there is no correlation and it does a seek through the index and finds that those 1000 rows are all in different blocks, in varying locations on the drive, it's going to have to do up to 1000 seeks to find said data. It might have been better to just bulk read the entire table from beginning to end.  The extra seeks on the index just made it worse, and bulk reads are now not going to do much to improve the speed.

Please let me know if this helps explain it at all.

Comment: I agree with everything you said (thanks for answering), but it still isn't clear to me how correlation would help, if, at each leaf node of the secondary index, it would still have to change head positions to read some other location where the actual data is.  Or, are you suggesting that the read head somehow stays put over the clustered index, while something else is reading the secondary B-tree index?

Comment: To be clear here, I am _not_ thinking of a bitmap scan, but rather a pure index scan.

Comment: Imagine a that your table had a billion rows. the query says "where id between 1000000 and 2000000 and added_on between (some 3 day range)
So both are just fine for a range scan, but what it'd likely do is use the stats to guess at which index would return the least rows and use that one, since both are pretty well correlated physically. Supposing it chose to use both, it'd scan both indexes (separately), but would still be left with a list of numbers that were mainly close to each other on disk.

Comment: I think you're  imagining that it looks up 1 row in the leaf, then jumps immediately to the data. It doesn't. It gets a list of what data it's going to need, then it goes and fetches it. If you tried to do it physically with an index and a book, you'd find that an alphabetical index combined with an alphabetized book is easier. (large encyclopedia with no subjects written at the top of the page).If you're looking for the subjects starting with "Q", is it easier to flip through and find them, or go to the index..

Comment: Actually, my understanding is in Postgres, an index scan in fact does do a lookup from each leaf.  There is something called a bitmap index scan.  This sounds more like what you are describing, where the database first reads the page locations from the index, _then_ goes off and does a (possibly sequential) read from the actual data.  So my question is how does correlation come into play in deciding whether seq scan, bitmap, or index scan gets used.

Comment: Do you think that the disk head reads only 1 leaf node per IO operation?

Comment: Yes, this was my general assumption; if it's wrong, then maybe highlight this in your answer.

Comment: In all reality though, I think it'd help to have an actual scenario where what you're describing (index scan on a 2nd correlated index) to really break down what's happening. The scenario sounds like something that wouldn't come up very often, if at all as every scenario I can imagine, 1 index would clearly be better than 2 when considering only index scans.

Comment: OK...so you're saying that the DB will read a few leaf nodes, then have a peek at what the I/O would look like.  If it looks like thrashing all over the place, then an index scan would be out, leaving bitmap scan or maybe no index as the available choices.  Is that right?

Comment: like I was saying.. I don't think that 2 index range scans on the same table would ever help.

Comment: I think I will have to add a bounty to this in a couple of days.  This concept is really poorly covered everywhere, even on SO, from what I can see.

Comment: Postgres aside, can you think of a reason why it'd make sense to try to use 2 indexes in range-scan fashion?

Comment: Who said anything about using two indices?  My question doesn't mention this, it only mentions a secondary index which might be used in the context of a join.

Comment: In that case it'll just be a single range scan then. Which I must not be wording properly, but just plain old range (index) scans are very common, and like I 've been saying, reduce the IO. Oracle has better docs on exactly how their stuff works (I'm an oracle certified DBA), but they have it well documented as to how much of an index is read in a single operation (configurable).. but I cannot find this info on postgres.

Comment: `but I cannot find this info on postgres` ... hence I am asking.  I am fairly familiar with how databases work, and I am clueless on this.